# Enumerate first 2^20 paths which don't include cycles between two vertixes

Tags: algorithm, cyclic-graph

Input is an undirected, cyclic, planar graph, with each vertex having at most 8 edges.

What is the way to enumerate over all paths betwen two vertexes v_0, v_1 in an order from shortest to longest? What is computational complexity?

If above is not possible, what is a way to generate all paths of length not longer than K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the shortest path  to the longest path -> indicates you can try BFS.

The path can't include the cycle -> you should storage the path have passed what vertices(when you do BFS).

The complexity: you can see the path don't include the cycle means the path can pass every node only one times. So the solution space is O(n!) and BFS may visit every path in the solution space in the worst case. So the complexity is O(n!).

You may be disappointed with that result. Okay, your problem is a famous problem that have been well studied. You can read this paper:

```
Finding the K Shortest Loopless Paths in a Network
Jin Y. Yen
```

Or the [wikipedia pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm) for a intuitive view for the K-th shortest path problems.

Comment: yen's algorithm has complexity `O(k N (M + N log N ))`, N, M being the number of vertices and edges in your graph, respectively, k the number of shortest paths you're interested in ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm)). with straightforward data structures you need time `O(k N^3)`. thanks to planarity, `M = O(N)` (instead of `O(N^2)` in the general case) so you have `O(k N^2)`. yen does not allow for loops. however, [eppstein's algo](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-SJC-98.pdf) can handle them running in `O(M + N log N + k N)` (`O(N log N + kN)`). ...

Comment: ... if you are enumerating _all_ paths between two vertices, among others you also find the [longest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), a problem which is known to be NP-hard.

Comment: It definitely should be NP-Hard. But it's not contrast with my naive solution(It's O(n!)).

Comment: the comments weren't meant to qualify your claim. however, you seem to derive the `O(n!)` from the fact that in the worst case, any permutation of the set of all nodes is a legal path. this would not be correct for planar graphs. anyway, fwiw [this site](http://assert-false.net/callcc/Guyslain/Works/tableau) seems to compile most known results with references to the literature.

Comment: Oh,I ignore the planarity of his problem. Now I admit the naive method is may be not with the complexity O(n!)...But I have no idea of complexity of that naive algorithm now...

Comment: @Sayakiss Thx. I didn't know the name of the problem. I'm investigating different approaches to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_Soccer AI.